# How To Enable SoapClient in PHP 7.0 Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, soap, soap-client

Im using PHP 7.0 Ubuntu 18.10, and I cant enable the module SoapClient in my phpinfo().

I already remove the ";" in my php.ini configuration and restart the apache2 to enable the soap module.

```
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=soap
```

And when I check the phpinfo() here's what I get.

[image]

Checked also if soap already install my server.

```
root@localhost:~# apt-cache search php | grep -i soap
libnusoap-php - SOAP toolkit for PHP
php-soap - SOAP module for PHP [default]
php7.2-soap - SOAP module for PHP
python-pysimplesoap - simple and lightweight SOAP Library (Python 2)
python3-pysimplesoap - simple and lightweight SOAP Library (Python 3)
root@localhost:~#
```

Even above result, Im still trying to install php7.0-soap and here's what I get.

```
root@localhost:~# sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-soap
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-soap'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-soap'
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use `.dll`-files. Those are for Windows.

Comment: that config was there, i just remove the ";" in line of php_soap.dll

Comment: That's still for Windows, though. Can you do `php -v` from the command line or check the PHP version in your php info? As far as I know, Ubuntu 18 uses PHP 7.2, not 7.0. Try `apt install php-soap` and you should get the correct version. Just remember to restart Apache server or php-fpm (if your running nginx for example) after it's installed

Comment: ok my bad. it was 7.2. I tried `apt install php-soap` and here's what i get `php-soap : Depends: php7.2-soap but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: That's strange. Does it say why? You could try `apt install php7.2-soap` and see what that says.

Comment: `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-soap : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.10.1 is to be installed`

here's the full message from `apt install php7.2-soap`

Answer (score 5):

This Work For me too Ubuntu 18 with PHP 7.0

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap
```

Answer (score -3):

My problem was solved by running the lower commands in the terminal:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap`

Comment: In case of php version `7.3` use `sudo apt-get install php7.3-soap`. Check your PHP version using `php --version`.